# Write data from for loop into a dataframe pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I load data from yahoo finance using the motor_daily function. It takes in a list of tickers and gets me the data.
Here are the used libs:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import datetime as dt
import yfinance as yf
```

Here is the function definition:

```
def motor_daily(ticker_file):   
    tickers_list = ticker_file #SP100
    stocks = yf.download(tickers_list, start = start, end = tomorrow) #YYYY-MM-DD
    company_name = []
    ticker_code = []
    for ticker in tickers_list:
        loaded_ticker = yf.Ticker(ticker)
        tickers = ticker
        ticker_code.append(tickers)
    finance = pd.DataFrame(ticker_code)
    finance["Ticker"] = pd.DataFrame(ticker_code)
    finance["Ticker_start"] = finance["Ticker"].str.split('-').str[0]
    finance= finance.drop(columns=[0])
    stocks_close = stocks.Close
    stocks_close = stocks_close.reset_index()
    return stocks_close
```

```
def ticker_data(list):
    data = []
    for ticks in list:
        data.append(motor_daily(ticks))
    return data
```

The above function loads closing prices for each ticker / stock name in the list (therefore the loop) and stores this in data.

list_of_lists includes:

```
[['VOW3.DE', 'BMW.DE', 'BEI.DE', 'DPW.DE', 'FME.DE'],
 ['ISS.CO', 'LUN.CO', 'CARL-B.CO', 'TRYG.CO', 'SIM.CO']]
```

Output of print(ticker_data(list_of_list))

```
[ Date        BEI.DE     BMW.DE     DPW.DE     FME.DE     VOW3.DE
0 2021-03-10  86.860001  81.339996  43.650002  60.840000  196.020004
1 2021-03-11  86.139999  78.519997  44.549999  61.340000  192.039993
2 2021-03-12  87.080002  77.480003  45.060001  60.939999  190.220001
3 2021-03-15  86.959999  77.800003  44.919998  60.759998  194.779999
4 2021-03-16  87.680000  80.500000  45.580002  61.259998  207.850006
5 2021-03-17  88.260002  85.459999  45.419998  60.779999  230.800003,         
Date        CARL-B.CO      ISS.CO      LUN.CO    SIM.CO     TRYG.CO
0 2021-03-10     1012.0  122.599998  243.600006   768.0  135.399994
1 2021-03-11     1009.0  120.300003  235.300003   780.0  143.500000
2 2021-03-12     1006.0  121.150002  237.000000   772.5  143.699997
3 2021-03-15     1006.5  124.250000  236.300003   783.0  145.100006
4 2021-03-16      983.0  125.550003  236.100006   795.5  147.399994
5 2021-03-17      982.0  121.949997  230.300003   778.0  143.899994]
```

When I try to convert the output to a dataframe using:
df = pd.DataFrame(ticker_data(list_of_list)) output is

```
ValueError: Must pass 2-d input. shape=(2, 6, 6)
```

I cannot convert this to a pandas dataframe, how should I go about doing this?

Comment: Can you show your imports and function definitions please?

Comment: sure, I can, NP.

Comment: Added for ya mate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `motor_daily` has a bunch of unused elements.  Also, I had to define the start and end times.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import datetime as dt
import yfinance as yf

def motor_daily(ticker_list):
    start = pd.Timestamp('now').normalize() - pd.offsets.Day(7)
    end = pd.Timestamp('now').normalize() + pd.offsets.BusinessDay(0)
    return yf.download(ticker_list, start=start, end=end).Close

list_of_lists = [
    ['VOW3.DE', 'BMW.DE', 'BEI.DE', 'DPW.DE', 'FME.DE'],
    ['ISS.CO', 'LUN.CO', 'CARL-B.CO', 'TRYG.CO', 'SIM.CO']
]

df = pd.concat(map(motor_daily, list_of_lists), axis=1)

# I transposed for prettier printing
df.T

Date        2021-03-10   2021-03-11   2021-03-12   2021-03-15  2021-03-16
BEI.DE       86.860001    86.139999    87.080002    86.959999   87.680000
BMW.DE       81.339996    78.519997    77.480003    77.800003   80.500000
DPW.DE       43.650002    44.549999    45.060001    44.919998   45.580002
FME.DE       60.840000    61.340000    60.939999    60.759998   61.259998
VOW3.DE     196.020004   192.039993   190.220001   194.779999  207.850006
CARL-B.CO  1012.000000  1009.000000  1006.000000  1006.500000  983.000000
ISS.CO      122.599998   120.300003   121.150002   124.250000  125.550003
LUN.CO      243.600006   235.300003   237.000000   236.300003  236.100006
SIM.CO      768.000000   780.000000   772.500000   783.000000  795.500000
TRYG.CO     135.399994   143.500000   143.699997   145.100006  147.399994
```

Comment: can I use group by on date?

Comment: Looks good, thanks for the optimization of motor_daily

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate through ticker_data(list_of_list) and make multiple dataframes:

```
lol = [['VOW3.DE', 'BMW.DE', 'BEI.DE', 'DPW.DE', 'FME.DE'],
 ['ISS.CO', 'LUN.CO', 'CARL-B.CO', 'TRYG.CO', 'SIM.CO']]

res = ticker_data(lol)
dataframes = [pd.DataFrame(lst) for lst in res]
print(dataframes[0])

#
           Date     BEI.DE     BMW.DE     DPW.DE     FME.DE     VOW3.DE
0    1996-11-08        NaN  18.171000        NaN        NaN         NaN
1    1996-11-11        NaN  18.122000        NaN        NaN         NaN
2    1996-11-12        NaN  18.259001        NaN        NaN         NaN
3    1996-11-13        NaN  18.230000        NaN        NaN         NaN
4    1996-11-14        NaN  18.289000        NaN        NaN         NaN
...         ...        ...        ...        ...        ...         ...
6241 2021-03-11  86.139999  78.519997  44.549999  61.340000  192.039993
6242 2021-03-12  87.080002  77.480003  45.060001  60.939999  190.220001
6243 2021-03-15  86.959999  77.800003  44.919998  60.759998  194.779999
6244 2021-03-16  87.680000  80.500000  45.580002  61.259998  207.850006
6245 2021-03-17  88.260002  85.459999  45.419998  60.779999  230.800003
```

Comment: Is there a way in which I can merge the dataframes to a single DF instead of having to go through the different dfs in the df?